# Need to update an overwrite permission for a specific role [Discord.js V12]

Tags: discord.js

How to update the overwrite of a specific role? I want @Player to talk in a specific channel when triggering the command, I don't know how `overwritePermissions()` works I'm using Discord.js V12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly overwritePermissions, like it says overwrites all the permissions, you might want `updateOverwrites` instead

Both require a role resolvable or user resolvable, so the first step is to get that role:

```js
const guild = <Guild>;
const role = guild.roles.cache.get(role_id);
const role2 = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Player");
```

After you get that role you need a channel to change the permissions in:

```js
const guild = <Guild>;
const message = <Message>;
const channel = message.chanenl;
const channel2 = guild.channels.cache.get(channel_id);
const channel3 = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "name-here");
```

After that you can just use the method:

```js
channel.updateOverwrite(role, { VIEW_MESSAGES: true, SEND_MESSAGES: true });
```

or

```js
channel.overwritePermissions([
  {
    id: role.id,
    allow: ["VIEW_MESSAGES", "SEND_MESSAGES"]
  }
]);
```

Comment: Btw it would be better to specify that each one of the `const` you made is a different way to get  the resolver. my final code was
-------
`const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("726355606440771646");
 const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("726313177066766377");
 channel.updateOverwrite(role, { VIEW_MESSAGES: true, SEND_MESSAGES: true });`

Comment: > so the first step is to get that role, After you get that role you need a channel. Both of those statements implied the following code would showcase that, especially considering I named the variables `x1`, `x2`, `x3`